# Two-Way ANOVA with significant interaction with replication, how to proceed?

Tags: anova, interaction, replicability

I am performing an omnibus two-way ANOVA test. In the set of factors that I want to test I included biological replication and technical replication.

The function used for the test was:

```
anova(lm(var~fac1*tech_rep*biol_rep, data = data))
```

I had a significant effect on fac1, and biol_rep, but also a significant interaction with `fac1:biol_rep`.
I decided to run independent ANOVAs for the levels of the two factors. Is this approach correct?

Comment: You want to stay with your one omnibus model.  You can use the `emmeans()` function in the *emmeans* package to break out the effects of the levels of the interaction of `fac1` and `bio_rep`.